# python 3 print on the same line using visual-studio-code IDE

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am trying to print test on the same line using python 3 as follow:

```
for i in range(3):
    print('Some text here....', end='')
```

it works fine with the Jupyter notebook as follow:

```
Some text here....Some text here....Some text here....
```

however that doesn't work on Visual studio code, as the result in the debug window looks like this:

```
Some text here....
Some text here....
Some text here....
```

also if I change the `end=''` to `end='&&&'` then the outcome will be:

```
Some text here....
&&&
Some text here....
&&&
Some text here....
&&&
```

so this seems to be related to visual studio code not python.
in visual-Studio-code the outcome is printed in the debug console not the output tab.

so how can I mange this to print on the same line for vs-code.

Comment: Try flushing the buffer: print('Some text here....', end='', flush=True)

Comment: @ifma that didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure

But `end=''` will remove last character of the line which is presumed to be (\n) i.e newline.

Howver I think vscode append two hidden characters (\n) and (\r)

So one of them is removed and the other will cause the newline.